# yshift/xshift used with (current bounding box.north)

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following code comes from the `pgf` manuel:

```
Top align:
\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]
\draw (0,0) rectangle (1cm,1ex);
```

I intend to raise a bit the baseline on this position(current bounding box.north) by 3pt, so I tried by `yshift` like this:

```
Top align:
\tikz[baseline=[yshift=3pt](current bounding box.north)]
\draw (0,0) rectangle (1cm,1ex);
```

but it fails to pass compile.

Anyone can help me with my question?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\begin{document}
Top align:
    \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (1cm,1ex);
\end{document}
```

Comment: Correct is `\tikz[baseline=([yshift=3pt] current bounding box.north)]`.

Comment: @Zarko I tried with your suggestion, but it still failed to compile.

Comment: oh, i forgot on curly braces around coordinate. correct is `\tikz[baseline={([yshift=3pt] current bounding box.north)}]`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your soluntion!!

Comment: I,m just curious, why you like to have box below baseline?

Comment: I need a flexible solution to get the position of pic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me convert and expand my comment(s):

- define position with use of `current bounding box`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
Top align:
    \tikz[baseline={([yshift=1ex] current bounding box.north)}]
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (1cm,1ex);
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: `shift` from some coordinate had to be inside parents in which is coordinate written: `([yshift=...] <coordinate>)`. If the coordinate is given as an option (to `tikzpicture` or to determining of a some `\coordinate`) in square bracket, than it should be encapsulated by curly braces as is done in above MWE.

- define position without use of `current bounding box`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
Aligned with a text    
    \tikz[baseline]
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (1cm,1ex);
and displaced for some amount:
    \tikz[baseline=2ex]
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (1cm,1ex);
```

[image]